# Can't get MySQL Connector/C++ to work - Unhandled exception (sql::SQLException) Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, boost, connector

So I have been trying to get a basic connection to a MySQL database for a few days now, and I have tried every which way there seems to be to get the MySQL Connector/C++ to work. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_driver.h>

int main(){
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("http://localhost/", "root", "");

    delete con;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using MSVS2010, MySQL Connector/C++ 1.1.6, Boost 1.5.9
I have the correct includes, and libraries along with the linker set up for the connector. I have also included boost 1.5.9.

When I compile and execute, I get the same error every time:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x75d9c42d in MySQL Test.exe: Microsoft C++
exception: sql::SQLException at memory location 0x0041f140..
```

Here is the Call Stack:

```
>   MySQL Test.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x17 bytes
```

And here is the relevant code:

```
550    #ifdef WPRFLAG
551        __winitenv = envp;
552        mainret = wmain(argc, argv, envp);
553    #else  /* WPRFLAG */
554        __initenv = envp;
555        mainret = main(argc, argv, envp);
556    #endif  /* WPRFLAG */
```

I have tried reinstalling the MySQL server and it's components, as well as the connector itself, and I have the correct .dll in the same directory as the Release.

I am trying to connect to a WAMP server, but I don't think it's particularly relevant to the error.

I also tried different versions of MSVS, including 2008 and 2013. I have no idea what the problem is, and there doesn't seem to be any solutions to this issue anywhere online.

I would like to try using CMake to build MySQL Connector/C++ from the source code myself, however I have no idea where to begin, and I don't to want to spend more time aimlessly going in the wrong direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Run the debug build in the debugger.

Comment: I've tried this and exactly the same error occurs

Comment: Yes, of course. But the debugger will show you the details of the exception, including messages, better location information, etc.

Comment: That is the only error that comes up? Unless I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Are you running it in the debugger? When the exception is thrown, the debugger should stop. Then you  can examine the exception object to see what caused the exception.

Comment: I don't think so, I don't know how to

Comment: CMake generates a VS project file. Open the project file in VS, and run it from there.

Comment: Should I use CMake on the mysql connector source code? When I do I always get errors

Comment: Unless you know you have a need for CMake, don't use CMake. Why overcomplicate your life?

Comment: Well I've read online that you run into a lot less problems if you build the library yourself, however I have no idea how to do this and when I did some research I was told I needed cmake to do it.

Comment: Since you are using windows you can use the pre-built windows distribution.

Comment: Right, but when I use the binary version, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to get it working, not however with MySQL Connector/C++ I had to use MySQL Connector/C, which worked first time, no problems at all.